# explode function and array element reading

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [php explode and array index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4639265/php-explode-and-array-index)

I am new to PHP and would like to ask if there is a way to 
write a php code like

```
$lengthofstay = ($duration <= 0 ? 'optional' : explode("_", $duration )[0]);
```

i mean calling the explode function and at the sametime reading the first element of resulting array.

Answer (score 1):

it would be possible in 5.4

but your code is as ugly as hell.
there is nothing good in writing all the code in one line.

Write in in three lines and when you come across it in a week, you wouldn't stumble upon it, puzzled.

```
if ($duration <= 0) 
  $lengthofstay = 'optional';
} else {
  list($lengthofstay) = explode("_", $duration, 1);
}
```

nothing wrong with it.

if you want to make it strictly one-liner - create a function. and then call it

```
$lengthofstay = get_length_of_stay($duration);
```

it's shorter than your cunning construct and way more readable

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use the limit-parameter from explode:

```
explode("_", $duration, 1)
```

Comment: It will still return an array.