# PHP: How to access the first element of an array returned by a static function

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [php explode and array index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4639265/php-explode-and-array-index)

In PHP 5.3...

I have a dynamic static method that always returns an array. In some cases it will return an array containing only one element. I want to assign, in one statement, the first element of the array to a variable. At the moment I have to do this:

```
$user = User::findByEmail($_SESSION['email']);
$user = $user[0];
echo $user;
```

I want to avoid the part...

```
$user = $user[0];
```

I expect something like this to work:

```
$user = User::findByEmail($_SESSION['email'])[0]; // not working
```

or

```
$user = User::findByEmail($_SESSION['email'])->get(0); // not working
```

or

```
$user = User::findByEmail($_SESSION['email']).get(0); // not working
```

Comment: You can't avoid it unless you have PHP  5.4.  5.4 will allow you to do `$user = User::findByEmail($_SESSION['email'])[0];`

Comment: `array_shift(User::findByEmail($_SESSION['email']))` will complain that it isn't getting an array reference.

Comment: The two get() versions would only work if findByEmail returned an object anyways.

Comment: Updated my answer with the solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT**

The solution you want is this:

```
$user = current( User::findByEmail( $_SESSION['email'] ) );
```

Note that using `current()` with functions always returns the first element, because the array was never assigned to a variable, and does not have a point. This is NOT the case if the function returns an array by reference.

Comment: @GuillaumeBois If you want elegant, upgrade to PHP 5.4 :)

Comment: This has been bugging me for years. And ```current``` is actually the only proper solution to retrieving the first (not index [0]) element from an array when using the value returned by a function.

Answer (score 2):

You can't (prior to PHP 5.4). It's a limitation of PHP's parser. Your best bet:

```
$user = User::findByEmail($_SESSION['email']);
$user = $user[0];
```